# Streaming HTTP responses with Jetty AsyncProxyServlet

Tags: java, jetty

I have a server that streams various things such as log output over long-lived HTTP responses. However, when using Jetty's proxy servlets, I haven't been able to get it to stream the response (it buffers the whole response before sending).

Using overriding a plain `ProxyServlet` class, the following appears to work:

```
@Override
protected void onResponseContent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Response proxyResponse, byte[] buffer, int offset, int length, Callback callback) {
    super.onResponseContent(request, response, proxyResponse, buffer, offset, length, callback);
    try {
        response.getOutputStream().flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.warn("Error flushing", e);
    }
}
```

However, doing that when overriding an `AsyncProxyServlet` doesn't work. (Full source code [here](https://github.com/danielflower/app-runner-router/blob/master/src/main/java/com/danielflower/apprunner/router/web/ReverseProxy.java).)

So, two questions:

1. When using `ProxyServlet`, is flushing after each bit of content received the way to go?
2. Is there a way to make it work with `AsyncProxyServlet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working. The proper approach works whether async is used or not, which is to set the output buffer size when creating the Jetty server connectors.

```
HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setOutputBufferSize(1024);
ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(jettyServer,
        new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
```

The default is 32768.

(Note: no need to override the `onResponseContent` method)